# HTML DOM Object / Property as a variable problem

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Trying to create a selector/variables in javascript but I can't get it to work.

**This one doesn't work.**

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(ID).checked;
checkbox = true;
```

**This one works**

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(ID);
checkbox.checked = true;
```

**What is the difference?**

Which part of the javascript rules have I managed to avoid by accident ?

**EDIT**

thanks, I understand now that I am storing the value not a reference in the variable. is it possible to save a direct reference to checked or is it impossible?

Comment: in the first case you are setting the `checkbox` variable with the value of the `checked` property of the `Element` object and later you are just changing the value of that variable that is no way related to the initial object. In the second case you are actually changing the `checked` property value of the object

Comment: A variable is never a reference to a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is very simple. lets understand by a simple example.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('vehicle1').checked;
checkbox = true;
```

Above you simply extracted the value of checkbox and later making change in the variable directly which has no relation directly with the DOM element by id vehicle1

and In the below example you simply tried to change the checked value of checkbox directly.

```
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('vehicle1');
checkbox1.checked = true;
```

The proper reference example will be something like this

```
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('vehicle1');
var dummyCheckbox = checkbox1
dummyCheckbox.checked = true;
```

you can go through this article to get the idea [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-assigning-values-vs-assigning-references/#:~:text=When%20we%20assign%20a%20reference,variable%20affect%20the%20original%20value.&text=In%20the%20example%20above%2C%20the%20variable%20array2%20is%20assigned%20a,to%20the%20original%20array%20array1%20](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-assigning-values-vs-assigning-references/#:%7E:text=When%20we%20assign%20a%20reference,variable%20affect%20the%20original%20value.&text=In%20the%20example%20above%2C%20the%20variable%20array2%20is%20assigned%20a,to%20the%20original%20array%20array1%20).

Answer (score 0):

**reference and value type**

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(ID).checked;
checkbox = true;
```

that checkbox is bool, it is just a value

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(ID);
checkbox.checked = true;
```

that checkbox is object, it is input element itself
you can modify it's property

try

```
typeof checkbox
```